# How can low frame rate video be made to look more smooth?

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I am trying to clean up a video that was recorded in 2003 in low-light conditions on what was possibly a cameraphone. The video has been cleaned up somewhat (cropped, logos removed and stabilized), but it remains quite jerky, due in large part to its low frame rate. What are some tricks that might clean up the video in this regard? I feel that I am asking for something a bit like tweening in flash animations, but for pixels, whereby additional frames are generated using nearby frames of the video. Does such a trick exist? Is there another way to approach this problem?

To reproduce the video processing so far, take the following steps:

```
# get video
wget http://www.anwarweb.net/saddamdown.wmv
# crop
ffmpeg -i saddamdown.wmv -filter:v "crop=292:221:14:10" -c:a copy saddamdown_crop.wmv
# remove logo 1
ffmpeg -i saddamdown_crop.wmv -vf delogo=x=17:y=77:w=8:h=54 -c:a copy saddamdown_crop_delogo_1.wmv
# remove logo 2
ffmpeg -i saddamdown_crop_delogo_1.wmv -vf delogo=x=190:y=174:w=54:h=8 -c:a copy saddamdown_crop_delogo_1_delogo_2.wmv
# stabilize
ffmpeg -i saddamdown_crop_delogo_1_delogo_2.wmv -vf deshake saddamdown_crop_delogo_1_delogo_2_deshake.wmv
```

Note: The video is of the Saddam Hussein execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with slowmoVideo: https://github.com/slowmoVideo/slowmoVideo
It's an open source software to create smooth slow motion effects from pixel motion analysis (Windows, Linux, OSX with wine or crossover. Read and write with ffmpeg).

First calculate the slow down ratio: for example if the original video is 18fps and the desired output is 24fps, set the speed of slowmo to 75% (18/24=0.75).
The result depends a lot on the video content, obviously the more fixed are the shots the better.
Anyway you can tweak what they call "Optical Flow", that is the analysis part of the process.
Good luck ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I haven't yet had slowmoVideo complete the rendering because it keeps crashing, but the idea of it looks to be exactly what I want. Thanks